# Swift “use of undeclared type” for Objective-C library

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I want to use the Objective-C library https://github.com/ameingast/cocoaimagehashing in a Swift project. I installed it with Cocoapods.
I cannot use it, it throws the following errors when I build: “use of undeclared type” or "Use of unresolved identifier".

It is surprising that when I write OSImageHashingProvider and click on it, it jumps in the .h file it is defined.

I added a bridging header in the project, but I don’t have reasons to believe it is active.

I added it in Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - General / Objective C Brigding Header.

Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags has -ObjC. and -l “CocoaImageHashing”.

My pod is :

```
target 'Projectname' do
    pod 'CocoaImageHashing', :git => 'https://github.com/ameingast/cocoaimagehashing.git'
end
```

I don’t use use_frameworks! because it throws an error at build.

What is the solution?

Comment: Did you `import CocoaImageHashing` at the top of your Swift file?

Comment: It doesn't accept it, says 'No such module 'CocoaImageHashing' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that Cocoapods does not install correctly this specific library.

At Target level, in Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths:
there is a path generated by Cocoapods that does not correspond to any actual folder structure: "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/CocoaImageHashing" when the /Headers/Public structure does not exist.
I removed that and remained with ${PODS_ROOT}/CocoaImageHashing , corresponding to the folder Projectname/Pods/Pods-Projectname.debug.xcconfig and now the library was seen.